# django queryset get object from filter

Tags: python, django

for implementation of django-likes i need `objects` that's gonna use in {% like object %}. if i am using `object = Article.objects.get(pk=1)` then the like system for particular article working fine. But i am using filter because i need particular filed values for template language. From filter or any other method can i get object so my like system will work ?

views

```
settings = Article.objects.filter().values('title','content', ..).order_by('-creation_date')
template_var['settings'] = settings
```

html

```
{% for x in settings %}
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ x.title }}</h2>
        <p>{% likes object %} </p>
        <p class="blog-post">{{ x.created }} by <a href="#">{{ x.user__username }}</a></p>
            <p>{{ x.content }}.</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the question how can i get each object out of from settings currently i am getting list because of filter api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use `filter()`, and don't use `values()`, then you'll get a queryset of articles

```
articles = Article.objects.filter().order_by('-creation_date')
```

If you then loop through `articles` in your template, you will have `article` objects that you can use with the template tag. You can still use access attributes like `{{ article.created }}` as before.

```
{% for article in articles %}
<h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ article.title }}</h2>
    <p>{% likes article %} </p>
    <p class="blog-post">{{ article.created }} by <a href="#">{{ article.user.username }}</a></p>
        <p>{{ article.content }}.</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i don't know why i tried with values before. Your answer helped me.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. The [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values) method can be a useful optimisation, but you don't need to use it most of the time.